# Using JComboBox as Cell Editor in JTable and saving changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am using a `JComboBox` as a cell editor for my `JTable`. When I select one of the values from the drop down list of the ComboBox, `setValueAt` is not getting called. I know this because I have overridden the function. Based on the value selected in this cell, the value in another cell of the same table is fixed. Also, I need to know which is the `actionListener` for this event, i.e when I change the value in the ComboBox.

The `setValueAt` does get called only when the focus is changed to another cell in the table, just clicking outside the table also does not help.

```
@Override 
public void setValueAt(Object o,int row,int col)
{
    super.setValueAt(o, row, col);

    if(((String)o).matches("1"))
    {
        super.setValueAt(o, col-1, row+1);
        return;
    }

    if(((String)o).contains("/"))
        super.setValueAt(((String)o).substring(2), col-1, row+1);
    else
        super.setValueAt("1/"+(String)o, col-1, row+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the way...

I need to add an actionListener to the JComboBox component that I created as a member of the CellEditor class and in the listener function, i need to call stopCellEditing so that the setValueAt gets called...